# Problem Building a Java Play Application using Maven - Sass compiler Unknown error, try running sass directly

Tags: java, scala, sass, playframework, sbt

I am trying to build a play framework app using maven, I am using MacOS Catalina.

I have configured:

- Maven all working by itself
- Using java 1.7
- Installed SBT and on path
- Installed Scala 2.11.6

My problem after cloning the repo from bitbucket and importing as SBT in Intellij. `mvn clean install` fails.

It fails at the test stage with the following error:

```
     java.lang.Exception: 
        Sass compiler: Unknown error, try running sass directly
        File: application.scss
        Line: 0 Col: Some(0)
                at sass.SassCompiler$.compile(SassCompiler.scala:35)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(SbtSass.scala:55)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(SbtSass.scala:43)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
                at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$6.apply(SbtSass.scala:43)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$6.apply(SbtSass.scala:39)
                at com.typesafe.sbt.web.incremental.package$.syncIncremental(package.scala:228)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5.apply(SbtSass.scala:38)
                at sass.SbtSass$$anonfun$5.apply(SbtSass.scala:33)
                at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
                at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
                at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
                at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
                at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
                at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
                at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
                at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
                at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
                at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
                at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        [error] (web-assets:sass) java.lang.Exception: 
        [error] Sass compiler: Unknown error, try running sass directly
        [error] File: application.scss

[error] Line: 0 Col: Some(0)
[error] Total time: 26 s, completed 21-Jan-2021 22:31:21
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:29 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-21T22:31:21Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.nanoko.playframework:play2-maven-plugin:1.2.5:test (default-test) on project user-portal: Error during compilation: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.nanoko.playframework:play2-maven-plugin:1.2.5:test (default-test) on project vdr-customer-portal: Error during compilation
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during compilation
        at org.nanoko.playframework.mojo.Play2TestMojo.execute (Play2TestMojo.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.nanoko.playframework.mojo.Play2TestMojo.execute (Play2TestMojo.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I did install sass as follows and rerun the build, but no luck:

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

And checked it was successfully installed :

```
sass --version
```

That did not fix.
I saw a post that says node-sass should be used instead and I did try that but no luck.

**POM** has

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <scala.majorminor.version>2.11</scala.majorminor.version>
        <scala.version>${scala.majorminor.version}.4</scala.version>
        <play.version>2.3.4</play.version>
        <joda.version>2.2</joda.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.9</jackson.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.1</logback.version>
     
    </properties>

     <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.nanoko.playframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.5</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executableName>sbt</executableName>
                        <testLib>test-lib</testLib>
                        <buildWar>false</buildWar>
                        <stage>true</stage>
                        <deleteDist>false</deleteDist>
                        <buildDist>false</buildDist>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**It has the following build.sbt**

```
import play.twirl.sbt.Import._
import WebJs._
import scoverage.Coverage

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).enablePlugins(SbtWeb)

pipelineStages += rjs

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

// The properties are passed down from the Nanoko Play2 Plugin when executing build via maven

scalaVersion := Option(System.getenv("scala.version")).getOrElse("2.11.4")

PlayKeys.playVersion := Option(System.getenv("play.version")).getOrElse("2.3.4")

name := Option(System.getenv("project.artifactId")).getOrElse("user-portal")

version := Option(System.getenv("project.version")).getOrElse("local-build")

// The dependencies are passed down as unmanaged by
// the Nanoko Play2 Plugin when executing build via maven.  Note the lib dir.

//resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Server" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.11-1"
)

excludeFilter in Assets := "*.scss"

fork in Test := false

parallelExecution in Test := false

unmanagedBase in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-lib"

ivyLoggingLevel := UpdateLogging.Quiet

logLevel := Level.Error
```

**Plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
//logLevel := Level.Warn
logLevel := Level.Error

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

resolvers += "corux-releases" at "http://tomcat.corux.de/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"

resolvers += "corux-snapshots" at "http://tomcat.corux.de/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += Resolver.url("ShaggyYeti repository", url("http://shaggyyeti.github.io/releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("default" % "sbt-sass" % "0.1.7")

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" %% "sbt-scoverage" % "0.99.5.1")

addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "findbugs4sbt" % "1.3.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.4.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.4")
```

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.17
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

The main cause was the following lines in the stack posted:

[error] (web-assets:sass) java.lang.Exception:
[error] Sass compiler: Unknown error, try running sass directly
[error] File: application.scss

After installing the sass compiler using brew, both outside and from within IntelliJ IDE, my scss was not getting compile automatically in when the Play application is run.

As part of trouble shooting I installed Code and used the Live Scss compiler to compile the culprit files. See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass

This fixed the mvn clean package and then the application started OK.

There should be a more stable fix of auto compiling the scss files.
Any ideas will be good.